# How to extract a part of string

Tags: java

My java program generates a set of lines as output like

```
Give input: 4+5
4+5 = <<9>>
```

The answer is displayed between <<   >>.
I just want to extract the answer 9. How can i do that? Should i use pattern matching?

Comment: Use regular expressions. Java has the required classes in package `java.util.regex`.

Comment: WHy would you need to extract it when you're outputting it?

Comment: You need to parse the output of your **own** program? Why not just make it do something useful with `9` right there and then when it is computed?

Comment: If you do not require the << >> to be there why not remove the code that insert them instead of adding new code to remove them?

Comment: @BrianRoach i'm executing one java program from another java program. So i need to catch hold of that value in order to go further.

Comment: what would this output though:
4+5+6?  I imagine it would output something like this:<<9>> + 6  which would then be morphed into:  <<<<15>>>>

Answer (score 3):

Here is some regex to help

```
    String answer = "<<9>>";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(answer);
    mat.find();
    answer = mat.group();
    System.out.println(answer);
```

If the string will always be in this format `<<n>>`, then @Sid solution is better as regex isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "<<9>>";

String prefix = "<<";
String postfix = ">>";

String answer = str.substring(prefix.length, str.indexOf(postfix));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some regular expression : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Or do it by hand using `indexOf`.